# CMD runs in terminal but not in .BAT

Tags: batch-file, terminal, command

I'm trying to combine all my commands into a .BAT file.  This line use to find and replace text in a file, works just fine in CMD, but when i put this in to a .BAT file, it does not.  I am using windows 7

```
powershell -Command "(gc src\template.html) -replace 'xxxxx', '%1' | Out-File src\%1.html"
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANivX.png)

After extensive googling, I guess the % needs to be an escape, however, when I do that, the filename becomes %1.html and not the variables of %1.hmtl.  How do I get the variables in?

Comment: just this one line in the batch file? How do you start it?

Comment: I guess the % needs an escape, but when I escape with %%, it just becomes a text and not picking up my variable.

Comment: `%1` stands for "first parameter" (no escaping needed). That's why I asked how you start it.

Comment: that's the only line right now.  If I do powershell -Command "(gc src\template.html) -replace 'xxxxx', '%%1' | Out-File src\%%1.html" I don't get an error, but it doesn't pick up my variable 1.

Comment: ok. How do you start it?

Comment: my .bath file name is "newproject", in cmd.  it's newproject "test" should produce an html file of test.html

Comment: `... Out-File %~1.html"` to remove the quotes.

Comment: wow, that works, thanks!.  canyou explain why it's ~?  thanks a lot !

Comment: The tilde `~` is the way, the programmers coosed to modify parameters: `%~1` is `%1` without surrounding quotes (no effect, if there are none) It's described (together with other useful modifiers) in the help of `call` (see `call /?`)